# Ununtu 12.04 to mipsel cross compile issue: /opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-ar: libsupc++.a : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cross-platform, mips, embedded-linux

I was using SDK with Ubuntu12.04 to cross compile for mipsel based board. But my system crashed and I reinstalled ubuntu12.04 and trying to set up environment and use the SDK to run make.

I do not have much knowledge of cross-compiling so while backing up data I just back-up **/opt/buildroot-gcc342/** folder which has cross compilers, libraries, include header needed for the SDK.

so now I was expecting everything should work all ok after /opt/buildroot-gcc342/ setup and updating the Ubuntu12.04 but SDK gives error while linking to libsupc++.a in uClibc++ make time.

**Detailed error is here:**

```
root@HOME_PC:/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source# make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++'
for dir in bin include src ; do \
        make -C $dir all; \
    done
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/bin'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/include'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/src'
make -C abi/libsupc all
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/src/abi/libsupc'
"/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin"/mipsel-linux-uclibc-ar x libsupc++.a
/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-ar: libsupc++.a: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [libsupc] Error 9
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/src/abi/libsupc'
make[2]: *** [libsupc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source/uClibc++'
make: *** [uClibc++_only] Error 2
root@HOME_PC:/home/Documents/mips_sdk/source#
```

I usually used to use tar zip folder and it use to work ok with old Ubuntu installation so this is also untar source which should be ok and something that I am missing should be in Ubuntu 12.04.

environment variable or some more setting to library path ??
Anyone has idea whats that I am missing ?

libsupc++.a file is in /opt/buildroot-gcc342/lib/ folder but seems like linker is not able to get this path. I tried setting :

export CONFIG_LIBDIR=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/lib:$CONFIG_LIBDIR

but have no luck .

I also tried to link this library in uClibc++ but then this error goes and some more other error.

can someone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally I solved this issue all by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue all by myself. I am mentioning solution which worked for me that may help others. I found this linking error in uClibc++ is very common if you just google it but I found many tricks suggested has no logical meaning. But I got some logical explanation and solution which worked for myself at least......so issue was, while backing up system I used "cp -r directory" and  rsync but this both are really not good to backup SDK, that's what  I now realized and I strongly recommend using tar for even any backup. tar is the only way one should go for while backing up SDK because it archive your all links in compressed folder as it is and that is most important while taking backup in Linux. ls -l to uClibc++ got that it use few links which gives this linking error. my SDK source was from tar but my back up of /opt/buildroot-gcc342 was cp -r and rsycn so links there all were absent. Finally i got /opt/ , SDK from tar and my check using ls -l shows there are many links in this folders which worked all OK without any error as my old linux setup.

Comment: Thanks for posting your own solution, it really helpful to me~